# How do you set up Stylus in Angular2 CLI project?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, stylus

I'd like to use Stylus instead of standard CSS in my Angular2 CLI project. I've had a look around and can't find any solid sources on how to set this up.

Comment: Different pre-processors are set via `--style` on `ng new` (plain css default). So `ng new --style styl <ProjectName>`. Pre-processing by included plugins, with no batteries included.

Answer (score 5):

When you start the project with Angular-cli run:

```
ng new my-app --style styl
```

Angular 6+
To change pre-processor on existing project run:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext styl
```

BELOW Angular 6
To change pre-processor on existing project run:

```
ng set defaults.styleExt styl
```

Answer (score 0):

Although correct the previous answer is out of date. If you try to run it you will get...

```
Error: Invalid values:
  Argument: style, Given: "styl", Choices: "css", "scss", "sass", "less"
```

Now you need to use one of the others like `ng new my-app --style sass`