# How to style html and body from the main Angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to style html and body from the main component:

**app.component.styl:**

```
 html, body {
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
       background: blue;
    }
```

and seems it does not work with my angular component:

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.styl']
    })
    export class AppComponent {

    }
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="todo-app">
  <div>
    <input type="text">
    <button>Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why html and body selector don't work, is there a special angular method to achieve that??

Comment: you can do it from the styles.css/scss file

Comment: If you are trying to use Stylus, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886486/how-do-you-set-up-stylus-in-angular2-cli-project

Comment: The `app.component` is located *inside* the index.html's body tag; so that component does not have access to body (if viewEncapsulation is enabled), if you target body or html from that component, styles will not appy. If you want to target html or body you should use the `styles` file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `app.component` is located *inside* the index.html's body tag; like this

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular Alerts</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon/favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root> <!-- This is your App Component -->
</body>
</html>
```

Given that, you can't target `body` or `html` with the default behavior (that means if ViewEncapsulation is enabled), since styles are scoped to that component only, and the component itself **DOES NOT** have a `body` tag; you need to define the styles in the `styles.css` global file, or turn ViewEncapsulation off for that component so the styles defined in its css file apply globally

Comment: Can you replicate your issue on stackblitz? the `styles.css` are global styles not scoped to any particular component, so there must be something else going on

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: But the problem is it becomes a global style. Won't be significant now but if all we try to apply some specific class style, should make sure it doesn't reflect else where.

Comment: @nishchalpro we are talking about a class needed to be applied on the `body` and `html` tags; you HAVE to target them from the global `styles` file or turn `ViewEncapsulation` off if you want to declare a class inside a component, otherwise the class won't affect the tags. If you want to style it only in certain cases you can use `ngClass`, but you would still need to declare de CSS rule in the `styles` file

Answer (score 3):

If you need that the style is apply to all project, you need to deactivate Encapsulation in css,

```
@Component({
   ...
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
   ...
})
```

[Here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html) a nice article about that.
But I recommend you set the style in style.css or style.scss in the root of your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd enabled **`Stylus`** preprocessor on your project, you have two ways AFAIN to apply your `Styles` on your root file.

**1-Through your general `styles.styl` file**

**2-Through the `index.html` file itself**